# OpenGL 3.2 Core Sprite Batch Example?

Tags: sprite, batch-processing, opengl-3, spritebatch

I have been tearing my hair out for a while over this. I need an OpenGL 3.2 Core (no deprecated stuff!) way to efficiently render many sprites, using batching (no instancing).

I've seen examples that do this with geometry alone, but mine also needs to send textures to it, I don't know how to do this.

I need a well done example of it working in action. And looking at how other libs like monogame and such do it isn't much help, because all I'm interested in is the GL code, and it has to have no deprecated stuff in it.

Basically I want to be able to efficiently render thousands+ of sprites, all having textures. The texture is just a spritesheet, so I just need to tell it to render a region of that spritesheet.

I'm disappointed in the amount of material available for programmable pipeline. To the point where it seems like it'd be so much easier to just say screw it and use fixed pipeline, even though I definitely don't want to do that.

So yeah, any full examples that do what I want? Or could somebody more knowledgable write one up? :)

A lot of the examples are "oh, here's how you render 1 triangle". Well that's great, except nobody needs to render only 1 triangle/quad. And they need to be textured in addition to that!

An example that uses VBOs/VAOs/EBOs

ALSO: this means the code can't use glTexPointer and that stuff, but just in raw VBOs/VAOs...

Answer (score 3):

I saw this question and decided to write a little program that does some "sprite" rendering using points and gl_PointSize. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "batching" as opposed to "instancing," but my program uses the glDrawArraysInstanced() call so that I can render multiple points without needing my VBO to be variable sized. My code also doesn't texture the sprites, but that's easy enough to add in (upload the active texture index (the one that was active during your call to glTexSubImage), to a GLSL sampler2D using glUniform1i).

Anyway, here's the program I wrote: http://litherum.blogspot.com/2013/02/sprites-in-opengl-programmable-pipeline.html Hope you can learn from it!